# Syntax error, ";" expected but identifier OBRADA" found, error in function but don't understand why

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Syntax error, ";" expected but identifier OBRADA" found, error in function but  don't understand why.. How come only happens to the second function but not in the first ? 
And could someone tell me if I used Delete correctly in this code ?

I had to make a program that counts integers in a string, and if 2 integers are the same remove all the duplicates of that integer. Write the new string, and the number of duplicate that has appeared most times... Could I have done it possibly easier then this ? 
Thanks in advance !

```
Program Zad_Septembar1_2013;

Const
  max = 100;

Type
  niz = array[1..100] Of integer;

Var A: niz;

Function citaj(Var A:niz;Var n:integer): boolean;
Var
  i: integer;
Begin
  citaj := true;
  writeln('Unesite duzinu niza');
  readln(n);

  If (n>0) And (n<=max) Then
    Begin
      For i:=1 To n Do
        Begin
          writeln('Unesite', i ,'. cifru');
          readln(A[i]);
        End     ;
    End;

  Function obrada(Var A:niz; Var n,q,s:integer): integer;
  {Here I get an error but i don't understand why}
  Var
    p,m,i: integer;
  Begin
    m := 0;
    q := 0;
    p := 0;
    s := 0;
    For i:=1 To n Do
      Begin
        p = A[i];

        For i:=1 To n Do
          Begin
            If (A[i]=p) Then
              Begin
                m := m+1;
                Delete(A[i]); {Did i use delete correctly ?}

              End;
          End;

        If (m>s) Then
          Begin
            s := m;
            q := p;
          End;
      End;
  End;

  Procedure ispis(Var A:niz; q,s:integer);
  Var
    g: integer;
  Begin
    g := length( A );

    For i:=1 To go Do
      write(A[i]);

    writeln('Broj pojavljivanja u nizu je: ',s);
    writeln('Broj koji se pojavljuje je:', q);
```

Comment: Learn to format your code. Line up matching `begin` and `end`'s.  You've got one or more extra `begin` and `end`'s somewhere in your code

Comment: If you format your code consistently, it will be easier to see what you're doing wrong. You have an imbalance in `begin` / `end` somewhere which is causing the `function obrada(...` to be misinterpreted.

Comment: I ran `ptop` (a basic Pascal formatter) on your code and edited your question. Now look it over and it should be obvious what the problem is.

Comment: Doesn't Lazarus have a formatter onboard? If not, it should get one ASAP.

Comment: OK, this is a personal preference, but although I am Dutch and live in Germany, I have never written any program that used German or Dutch variable or function names. It feels "unnatural" between all these English keywords and library function names. Of course the output was German or Dutch, sometimes.

Comment: BTW, please, use english to name your variables. It was nightmare when I work with project where all identifiers was named in france for example.

Comment: You also have a nested `for` loop using the same control variable `i`.

Comment: The more I look at it, the more problems I see.  Try to write your code in small incremental steps, e.g., a single function at a time, then compile and correct all errors, then write some more, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the missing 'end' at the end of 'citaj', you also appear to have an undeclared identifier in this statement For i:=1 To go Do... Using more descriptive variable names would help immensely.

Comment: "more descriptive variable names" for a simple loop counter? I always use I, J and K for those. A missing declaration will immediately be flagged anyway, even for short names.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Loop variables are one thing, but what about m, q, p and s?

Comment: I didn't say that one shouldn't use meaningful names at all, but it depends a little on where they are used and for what.